# Installing STY linux mint texlive not working

Tags: packages, texlive, installing, mhchem

I'm strying to install the `mhchem` package on my linux machine and it's not working. So far I've tried putting it in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mhchem` and then running `texhash` on that directory, `texhash` fails on that folder. I also tried it in `/home/<user>/texmf` which is the directory I get when I run `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME`. The directory did not exist so I had to create it. Running `texhash` on that directory succeeds and I get an `ls-R` file in the directory. However, when I try to run latex on a file that has `\usepackage{mhchem}`, it fails and says that the package does not exist.
Am I putting the `.sty` file in the right place?

Comment: Hi and welcome, does it say the file does not exist, or does it say it is not found? Put the file in `/home/<username>/texmf/tex/latex`, there should be no need to run `texhash`. Can't you install `mhchem` and related packages using the package manager of your distro?

Comment: That worked, thanks! I don't have any experience with package manager, I do almost everything through terminal, just my engineering way of making everything more difficult.

Comment: I bet there are good terminal package managers, you cannot do all of this including dependencies by hand. On Ubuntu, i have `apt-get` and `aptitude`, there some similar for Mint, i bet.

Comment: I use apt-get for most of what I do, I will certainly use a gui package manager if I need to, but as of yet I haven't needed to.

Comment: http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/texlive-science Seems to be in the package `texlive-science`, so `sudo apt-get install texlive-science` seems to be a good start.

Comment: btw, you might be interested in the chemistry related packages maintained and developed by our respected member @clemens, including `chemmacros`, `chemformula` ... ah, there are many.

Comment: Thanks for the options. I have mhchem working at the moment but if I run into something I can't do, I'll have a look at the other packages

Comment: @Johannes_B Your comments solved the problem. It would be nice if you could convert your comments into an answer so that the question can be flagged as answered.

Answer (score 3):

You can always place your custom packages in `/home/<username>/texmf/tex/latex`.
For packages coming with TeX Live, `tlmgr` (TeX Live manager) takes care of downloading and making the package available. If `sudo` was needed to install TeX Live, i.e. in a directory where a normal user has no writing rights, `sudo` will also be needed to run `tlmgr`.

If TeX Live was installed as part of the Linux-distribution, chances are that you are havin a quite old version and not all solutions on site work. Nevertheless, distros often bundle up TeX Live packages in distro-meta-packages.

For example, `mhchem` can be found in `texlive-science` according to the [Linux Mint community](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/texlive-science). The meta package will install other chemistry related packages like [chemstyle](http://ctan.org/pkg/chemstyle) and [chemmacros](http://ctan.org/pkg/chemstyle) as well.